# Fetching data from MongoDB or from file (memory)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file

I have price data (for about 2k items) in format:

```
{
  "item1": 420,
  "item2": 69,
  ...
}
```

After I save them I will randomly access prices by searching key.

What will be fastest and less performance eating solution?
I thinked about:

- MongoDB, load into memory on start
- MongoDB, read one by one when needed
- File, load into memory on start
- Some other suggestions?

Comment: 2k items like yours is nothing for actual memory capacity reality, just load everything into memory on start.

Comment: Its like 11MB JSON file. So its ok to just load it into memory from file or database and leave it sit here.

Comment: You can make indexes in mongo. You mention that you'll "randomly" be accessing prices, but if that's not completely accurate an index would speed it up. Eg if this is a store and there's a page showing the most recent items, an index on the created_at field would optimize a search that sorts by created_at